# Hadoop-Installation-Multinode

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning

Hi all I am trying to install the multinode hadoop installation. Everything works fine but my nodemanager for yarn is not working. When I looked at the log file for Yarn nodemanager, I got following information

> "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl:
>   Initialized nodemanager for null: physical-memory=-1 virtual-memory=-2
>   virtual-cores=-1"

I have no idea why its not showing the actual memory and virtual core. My VM has 8GB memory and 8Vcpus. Because of above values I am getting this error:

> "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved
>   SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager
>   failed, Message from ResourceManager: NodeManager from  SFeUbuntuVM2
>   doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the
>   NodeManager"

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have

1. Selinux disabled
2. firewall disabled

Check your configuration files.

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>{your host name}</value>
</property>
```

After all do format your namenode, and start all services again.